# Как вывести данные из одного столбца в одну строку через запятую?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос, который выводит данные о заказах и пациентах:

```
select
    fn_pat_name_by_id(p.keyid) AS fio
    ,TO_CHAR(p.birthdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') AS bd
    ,p_pat.address(p.keyid,1) addr
    ,s.text
from
    research r
    ,order o
    ,service s
    ,patient p
where
    o.research_id = r.id
    and o.service_id = s.keyid
    and r.patient_id = p.keyid
```

Как вывести данные в виде ФИО, Дата рождения, Адрес, Услуги, где данные в столбце услуги надо вывести как все услуги пациента в одну строку через запятую?

Пробовал так, но не помогает:

```
select
    fn_pat_name_by_id(p.keyid) AS fio
    ,TO_CHAR(p.birthdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') AS bd
    ,p_pat.address(p.keyid,1) addr
    ,(select listagg(s.text, ',') within group (order by s.text) from service s where s.keyid = o.service_id) as usl
from
    research r
    ,order o
    ,service s
    ,patient p
where
    o.research_id = r.id
    and o.service_id = s.keyid
    and r.patient_id = p.keyid
```

---

И еще одно замечание, в столбце Услуги в итоге может получиться большой текст, поэтому нужен тип `CLOB`.

Comment: Тоже пара замечаний к тексту вопроса: 1) фраза _но не помогает_ не является критерием оценки работоспособности запроса; 2) таблиц указанных в вопросе ни у кого кроме вас нету.

Comment: @Kolhoznik, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) PS при 121 заданном вопросе статистика показывает - `"Участник не отдал ни одного голоса"` - что-то не верится что вам совершенно не помог ни один полученный ответ

Comment: я уже решил проблему, и привел код ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Начать решение надо с создания минимального воспроизводимого примера. При этом, следует  абстрагироваться от бизнес логики реальной задачи. Идёт речь, о пациентах и их процедурах, или о студентах и их лекциях, для технической стороны вопроса это не играет абсолютно никакой роли.

В вопросе простая связь таблиц многие-ко-многим. Надо сгрупировать значения из одной таблицы и вывести к ним лист связанных значений из другой таблицы.

Подготовим таблицы:

```
create table foo (id int, name varchar2 (8), created date)
/
create table bar (id int, text varchar2 (8))
/
create table foobar (fooid int, barid int)
/
```

Заполним их исходными данными:

```
insert all 
    when 1=1 then into foo values (rn, 'name'||rn, date'2020-01-01'+rn)
    when 1=1 then into bar values (rn, 'text'||rn)
select rownum rn from dual connect by level<=3
/
insert into foobar 
    select foo.id, bar.id from foo, bar 
/
```

Теперь запрос, который выводит все данные, выглядит так:

```
select
    foo.name, foo.created, bar.text 
from foo, foobar, bar 
where foobar.fooid = foo.id 
and   foobar.barid = bar.id
/
NAME     CREATED             TEXT    
-------- ------------------- --------
name1    2020-01-02 00:00:00 text1   
name2    2020-01-03 00:00:00 text1   
name3    2020-01-04 00:00:00 text1   
[...]
name3    2020-01-04 00:00:00 text3
```

В итоге, запрос, который выведет желаемый результат:

```
select
    foo.name, to_char (foo.created,'dd.mm.yyyy') created, 
    listagg (bar.text, ',') within group (order by bar.text) textlist 
from foo 
join foobar on foobar.fooid = foo.id 
join bar on bar.id = foobar.barid 
group by foo.name, foo.created 
/
NAME     CREATED    TEXTLIST                
-------- ---------- ------------------------
name1    02.01.2020 text1,text2,text3       
name2    03.01.2020 text1,text2,text3       
name3    04.01.2020 text1,text2,text3
```

Всё очень просто и понятно всем. Любой может скопировать команды выше и воспроизвести пример. Когда техническое решение станет понятно, то  не составит особого труда заменить имена таблиц и колонок их реальными именами.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  fn_pat_name_by_id(p.keyid) AS fio
  ,TO_CHAR(p.birthdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') AS bd
  ,p_pat.address(p.keyid,1) addr
  ,listagg(s.text, ', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY s.text) AS usl
FROM
  research r
  ,order o
  ,patient p
  ,service s
WHERE
  o.research_id = r.id
  AND r.patient_id = p.keyid
  AND s.keyid = o.service_id
GROUP BY p.keyid, p.birthdate
```

Получилось так.

Comment: Извините, а получилось что? Запросы, ни в вопросе, ни в ответе в текущем виде никогда не работали и работать не будут. Скопировал [ваш запрос из ответа на фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5eb248edeb44a7015dce412fa30be22f), убедитесь сами.  В итоге, остаётсся не понятным, в чём заключался вопрос и как на него отвечает ваш "ответ".

Comment: В итоге мне нужно было, чтобы в поле usl выводились все услуги одного пациента через запятую. Первый мой запрос выводил их отдельными строками, Данный запрос из моего ответа выводит ФИО, Дату рождения, Адрес и в поле usl через запятую все услуги. Нужно было сделать группировку и переделать вывод поля usl

Comment: Вы наверное не совсем внимательно прочитали мой комментарий выше. Ваш запрос из ответа не может ничего вывести, т.к. он синтактически не верен. Но вы его и не сможете проверить, потому что не сможете создать таблицу `order`, это зарезервированое ключевое слово. Попробуйте всё таки пример на фиддле по ссылке в первом комментарии.